# Springboot2 + reactive + mongo => Tailable and Capped collection

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, project-reactor

I try to do some tests with Springboot2 espacially with Reactor (Flux/Mono).
I'm facing a problem.

When i try to use a repository method do retrieve all my persons i use that method : 
  @Tailable
  Flux findWithTailableCursorBy();

But in my case, i receive that error

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoQueryException: Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'error processing query: ns=test.person batchSize=2Tree: $andSort: {}Proj: {} tailable cursor requested on non capped collection' on server localhost:27017
```

When i set my collection to "capped" it works

```
db.runCommand( { convertToCapped: 'person', size: 8192 } )
```

But i won't use a capped collection for many reason

- Cannot delete document (have to drop collection)
- Connot set this property programaticaly

I don't know how to resolve this, maybe i'm wrong in my code or choice.

Can someone explain me how to use retrieve only new elements in my DB?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is by design, and not a Spring Data limitation. MongoDB supports Tailable cursors only on capped collections (see the [mongodb reference documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/tailable-cursors/)).

As explained in the linked document, you can choose to poll an indexed collection for new elements (I’m not aware of any reactive integration for that in Spring Data).

Comment: Hi Brian, ty for this response. So how can i keep the flux open, and retrieve only new éléments ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, I’m not aware of any spring data feature for that.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using `ReactiveMongoOperations` do not forget to subscribe the method like this: `mongoOperations.createCollection(ItemCapped.class, CollectionOptions.just(Collation.simple()).capped().size(50000).maxDocuments(20)).subscribe();`

Using spring `2.4.5`